# Detecting if a UIScrollView has the height to scroll

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uikit

I have a UIScrollView that sometimes has enough contentHeight to scroll and sometimes doesn't. I also have a button that's predicated on the user scrolling to the bottom of the scroll view.

Without the user taking an action, how do I detect if the scroll view has the contentHeight to scroll so I can set the default `isEnabled` of the button appropriately?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have all of your content in a top level content view (you should), then you can just check if the height of the contentView is greater than the height of the scrollView.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension on UIScrollView

```
extension UIScrollView {
  var contentUntilBotttom: CGFloat {
    return max(contentSize.height - frame.size.height - contentOffset.y, 0)
  }

  var isAtTheBottom: Bool {
    return contentUntilBotttom == 0
  }
}
```

In case you are using RxSwift you can observe changes like:

```
extension Reactive where Base == UIScrollView {
  var isAtTheBottom: ControlEvent<Bool> {
    let source = contentOffset
      .map({ _ -> Bool in
        return self.base.isAtTheBottom
      })
    return ControlEvent(events: source)
  }
}

// So then subscribe to it
scrollView.rx.isAtTheBottom
  .subscribe(onNext: { (isAtTheBottom) in
    // Update anithing you need
})
```